# How do I build Qt Static Libraries?

Tags: development, qt, libraries

I'm Developing QT and I want to know how to build static libraries.

Well, I searched a lot. But the Reason I asked is that I've installed these from Synaptic:

```
libqt4-core
libqt4-gui
libqt4-qt3support
libqt4-sql
qt4-designer
qt4-dev-tools
qt4-qtconfig
```

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Do you want to link those libraries statically into your application? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say:

```
$ ./configure --help
```

In help description you may find

```
--enable-static
```

option. Than's possibly the one you need.

```
$ ./configure --enable-static
$ make
```